# How powerful are the jutsu created with Scientific Ninja Tools?

Tags: boruto

If a ninja student or genin use scientific ninja tools, can they match the jutsu made by upper ranks, such as chunin or jounin? How about matching a kage?

How powerful are the jutsu created with Scientific Ninja Tools? Does their power have a limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there are various types of scientific ninja tools and each have different purposes, I'm assuming you are referring to the [Gauntlet](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Shinobi_Gauntlet) (based on how your question is phrased).

These tools are new to the Narutoverse as a whole, so there is little information on them both in and out of universe. However, based on the gauntlet wiki, it seems likely an academy student or genin would be able to "match" the power level of Jonin or Kage in a sense.

> The Gauntlet was developed by Katasuke of Konohagakure's Scientific Ninja Weapons Team as a way **to allow anyone (even non-shinobi) to use complicated jutsu without the need for training or the requisite skills**
>
> <sub>(Emphasis my own)</sub>

[Jutsu](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Jutsu) are not ranked by a power level, but rather the difficulty to perform based on chakra control and skill. The power of the jutsu is determined by the caster. If the caster does not have proper chakra control, the jutsu would be weaker than one who has excellent chakra control.

In order to use the Gauntlet, a jutsu would need to be sealed into a scroll cartridge to be used as "ammunition". So theoretically, the strength of the sealed jutsu would be based on the who would created the cartridge. So for example, if Sasuke were to created a cartridge using a fire-type jutsu, it would probably be more potent than if Sakura tried to do create a cartridge using the same jutsu. And then vice versa for medical jutsu